# Capturing JavaScript Error in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, error-handling

I am developing an automation tool where one of my requirement is to detect whether the input page contains any js error. I have tried using response but this is not wokring.

Can you please help me out as I am stuck very badly.

Comment: Read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638132/how-to-save-the-javascript-errors-in-file

Comment: your question is bit unclear. you want to check javascript code for errors or you want to check the user input via javascript ??

Answer (score 2):

You can't check if there is a JavaScript error on the page.

What you can do is on "trappable" errors, you can insert text into a hidden field and read that in your c# code.

But if there is an error in code then I don't think you'll be able to check that in c#.

Actually, you could have a hidden field on the page that already has text in it.  Then use JavaScript to clear out the field.

In c# code, if you can see an entry in the field, then there was an error in the JavaScript and if it's empty then the JavaScript ran ok and there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like described here? [Log client side js errors](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/logclientsidejserrors2srv.aspx)